# Как получить максимальный интервал между записями в SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Необходимо получить Максимальный интервал между транзакциями в днях по номеру счёта.

Какой максимальный период между крайними транзакциями. (не первой и последней), а условно первой и условно второй. Главное чтобы дней между первой и второй прошло больше ,чем между другими днями.

Как получить эту разницу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В CTE посчитать date-LAG(date) и снаружи взять максимум разности.

Comment: извините, я немного слабоват в SQL , можете пожалуйста поподробнее.